# Imbalanced dataset using MLP classifier in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am dealing with imbalanced dataset and I try to make a predictive model using MLP classifier. Unfortunately the algorithm classifies all the observations from test set to class "1" and hence the f1 score and recall values in classification report are 0. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

```
model= MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', activation='tanh')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
score=accuracy_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test), )
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
roc=roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
cr=classification_report(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few techniques to handle the imbalanced dataset. A fully dedicated python library "imbalanced-learn" is available [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn). But one should be cautious about which technique should be used in a specific case.

Few interesting examples are also available at https://svds.com/learning-imbalanced-classes/